# Gluon-gluon scattering: Problem 8.28 in Griffiths' "Intro. to Elementary Particles" (2nd edition)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory

The "Introduction to Elementary Particles Instructor's Solution Manual" (available online) does not give the solution to this particular problem, which asks: (a) Draw the lowest order diagrams (there are four of them) representing the interaction of two gluons (b) Write down the corresponding amplitudes (c) Put the incoming gluons into the color singlet state...

I've started with this diagram

[image: Gluon-gluon scattering]

(where $q' = - q$), and for the amplitude I have

$$\frac{\mathcal{M}_1}{i} = -i g_s^2 \int \epsilon_{3\mu'}^*a_3^{\alpha'*} f^{\alpha\beta\gamma} \left[g_{\mu\nu}(k_1-k_2)_{\lambda}+g_{\mu\lambda}(k_1-q)_{\nu} + g_{\nu\lambda}(k_2 - q)_{\mu} \right] \epsilon_{2\nu} a_2^{\beta} \; \frac{g_{\lambda \lambda'}}{q^2} \epsilon_{4\nu'}^* a_4^{\beta '*} f^{\alpha' \beta' \gamma} \left[g_{\mu'\nu'} (k_3-k_4)_{\lambda'}+g_{\mu'\lambda'} (k_3+q)_{\nu'} +g_{\nu'\lambda'} (k_4+q)_{\mu'} \right] \epsilon_{1\mu} a_1^{\alpha}  \; \frac{d^4q}{(2\pi)^4} \; (2\pi)^8 \delta^4(k_1+k_2+q) \, \delta^4(k_3+k_4-q)$$
($a^{\alpha}, \alpha=1...8$,  the color state of the gluon given by an eight-entry column matrix; $\epsilon^{\mu}, \mu=0...3$ its polarization four-vector).

Even if this is correct, I am stuck on the next step: prescribing that the incoming gluons (nos. 1,2) are in the color singlet state. An individual gluon can be in a color singlet state; or, is this intended to be a color singlet state of the incoming *pair*? Either way, I don't know how to force the choice onto the amplitude as I've given it. Perhaps each "$a$" (color state) becomes a linear combination?

This is one of the few problems from Griffiths' textbook for which a solution is not given, at least, anywhere that I've been able to find.

Comment: I've added the homework-and-exercises tag. Please use this tag on this type of question.

Comment: Will do. Thanks.

Comment: There is also a final question in the book: Determine whether the force is attractive or repulsive (if it is the former, this may be a likely glueball configuration). How would one determine, from the differential cross section, if the force between the two gluons is attractive or repulsive?